# UITextField with UIKeyboardType.NumberPad and nonnumeric text

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield

I'm using TextField to get from user number in specific form `xxx-xxx-xx-xx`.

I need to show user `NumberPad` keyboard and add separators "-", after 3,6 and 8th digit during editing.

The problem is that when i specify

```
TextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
```

and add separator in my `textFieldDidChange` method, TextField stops responding to adding next character or remove.

Changing to `UIKeyboardType.Default` works perfectly, but keyboard is not digit only.

Comment: you need 111-457- 33-33 this format? **-** is automatically inserted?

Comment: yes, this format. User inserting digits, I'm adding "-" separators automatically in textFieldDidChange method if needed.

Comment: Ok i have post answer, but not used `textFieldDidChange` method, you used `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method, its working

Comment: Moving my code to shouldChangeCharactersInRange works fine. Thanks.

Comment: my answer is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can use below code.

txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;

```
- (BOOL)textFieldPhoneDigit:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

@try
{
    NSString *filter = @"(###) - (###) - (####)"; //Change Fileter As Per requirement. 

    if(!filter) return YES; // No filter provided, allow anything

    NSString *changedString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if(range.length == 1 && // Only do for single deletes
       string.length < range.length &&
       [[textField.text substringWithRange:range] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"]].location == NSNotFound)
    {
        // Something was deleted.  Delete past the previous number
        NSInteger location = changedString.length-1;
        if(location > 0)
        {
            for(; location > 0; location--)
            {
                if(isdigit([changedString characterAtIndex:location]))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            changedString = [changedString substringToIndex:location];
        }
    }

    textField.text = filteredPhoneStringFromStringWithFilter(changedString, filter);

    return NO;

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Exception shouldChange %@",[exception description]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this below `UITextField` delegate method below,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{   
    if (textField == numberTextField)
    {
        if (range.location == 12) {
            return NO;
        }

        // Reject appending non-digit characters
        if (range.length == 0 &&
            ![[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[string characterAtIndex:0]]) {
            return NO;
        }

        // Auto-add hyphen before appending 4rd or 7th digit or 10th digit
        if (range.length == 0 &&
            (range.location == 3 || range.location == 7 || range.location == 10)) {
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", textField.text, string];
            return NO;
        }

        // Delete hyphen when deleting its trailing digit
        if (range.length == 1 &&
            (range.location == 4 || range.location == 8))  {
            range.location--;
            range.length = 2;
            textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
            return NO;
        }

        return YES;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

In shouldChangeCharactersInRange method works fine. Thx.